# NHibernate + ActiveRecord + as never load mapping?

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord

I have my classes mapped with belongsTo / hasMany / HasAndBelongsToMany / HasManyToAny. QueryOver I want to use to build my queries, I do not want is that the NH mapping automatically loads any, as I do that?

Note: does not solve Lazy as I use WCF.

Answer (score 0):

send DTOs with only the properties you need. then you can decide on a case by case basis what to send or not.

alternativly you could lazyload and hook into wcf to ignore uninitialized properties

```
var proxy = obj.PropertyWithReference as INHibernateProxy;
if (proxy != null && proxy.HibernateLazyInitializer.IsUninitialized)
    // ignore


var coll = obj.SomeCollection as IPersistentCollection
if (coll != null && !coll.WasInitialized)
    // ignore
```